# PL/SQL Developer GUI not showing number result in text format

Tags: plsqldeveloper

PL/SQL Developer is showing number results like `9.15734383345614E18`.
What config change is needed to show number result in text format?

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert it to char:

```
select F1 , to_char(F1) from T1;
```

or simply go to this path and do the config in PL/SQL Developer:

```
Configure -> Preferences -> SQL Window -> Number fields to_char
```

Comment: Thanks Davoud. It worked.

Path was 
Tools > Preferences > Window Types > SQL Window > Number fields to_char

Comment: Glad it worked. In my PL/SQL it's in configure. maybe it's because of the difference in versions. mine is 13.0. Goodluck.

Comment: Yes, they changed Tools > Preferences to a 'Configure' menu in version 12.